# How to establish synchronizing shared folder between multiple hosts?

Tags: bash, synchronization, filesystems

I would like to establish a shared folder between multiple linux hosts, such that:

- any host can make changes
- if the connection is lost, hosts make changes on the last synchronized version of the folder
- as soon as the connection is reestablished the folders merge the changes.

I was unable to find a tool for my problem, and I would like to check if anyone can point me to a solution, or give me tips on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One off-the-shelf would be Dropbox.  Setup a common account for all systems and the application will maintain file sync across all copies.  Local copies on the same network will sync across network connections without needing multiple downloads from the cloud copy.

Comment: The reason why I am trying to do this, is to avoid having to use cloud providers, so this won't work for me.